# Auth0 with react-native

Tags: react-native, auth0

I'm trying to [Example repo](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-native-sample/tree/master/00-Login-Expo). But when this call is executed: `const { accessToken } = await getCredentials();`, accessToken is `undefined`

I have created Auth0 Application and copy my `domain` and `clientId`

so plugins in `app.json` looks like this:

```
"plugins": [
      [
          "react-native-auth0",
          {
              "domain": "{MY_DOMAIN}"
          }
      ]
    ],
```

Also have `Auth0Provider` who looks like this:
`Auth0Provider domain={config.domain} clientId={config.clientId}`

`Callback` and `Logout` urls are all set. Here is image literally from provided example:

[image: example]

and `getCredentials` keep throwing `undefined` after client login with `Google`

Answer (score 1):

You can d two approaches here.

1. Using a `loader` and waiting until data loading.
2. Using `useEffect() with Promise()` or using only `useEffect()`.

in the `App.js`

```
const { user, getCredentials} = useAuth0();
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const getUserMetadata = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const tokenData = await getIdTokenClaims();
    if (tokenData) {
      localStorage.setItem(USER_OBJECT_KEY, tokenData['__raw']);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    const storedAccessToken = localStorage.getItem(USER_OBJECT_KEY);
    if (!storedAccessToken) {
      getUserMetadata();
    }
  }, [getCredentials, user]);

if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

return (
   Your code.....
)
```